# JQuery traversal problem

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to select the DIV with the class 'container'.

```
<a href="#" class="playButton">Start</a>
<div class="overlay">
<div class="overlayClose">Close</div>              
    <div class="container">Foo</div>
</div>
```

Using variations of the js below, which fails.
What is the smartest way to get this selection?

```
$('.playButton').click(function() {
   $('div').next('div').has('.container').css("background-color", "red");
});
```

Comment: What are you trying to do here? Is this the only case the code will be used in? Or do you want to generalize the solution?

Comment: Yes, would love to generalize.

Comment: Ok... so what is the general case that you're trying to solve for here? What order do the tags come in? Are there multiple links? Are there multiple overlays? Etc., etc., etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('.playButton').click(function() {
   $(this).next('.overlay')
                         .children('.container').css("background-color", "red");
});
```

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/F9dUN/1/

Answer (score 0):

This is probably neater:

```
$('.playButton').click(function(e) {
    $(this).next('.overlay').children('.container').css({ 'background-color': '#f00' });
});
```

Edited.  Neal beat me to it with is indentation-proof reading, but I didn't want to leave an incorrect answer.

Comment: that doesnt do anything, try it out in a fiddle

Answer (score 0):

Or, if the 'container' div is not used elsewhere on the page, simply:

```
$('.playButton').click(function(){
   $('.container').css({'background-color':'#F00'});
});
```